# How to create C# DLL to use in PHP

Tags: php, asp.net

I'm using a C#.NET DLL with ASP.NET 2.0 and it's working now. I want to use the same DLL in PHP.

I'm a newbie in PHP; would someone please tell me how to use it in PHP or could you share some example?

Comment: I don't know if you can use the same .dll. Anyway to add one you have to add this line to your php.ini extension=yourdll.dll

Comment: Please consider this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310821/how-to-call-asp-net-dll-file-from-a-php-script

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP has a [built-in Windows-only extension called DOTNET](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php) that allows you to use .NET libraries in a PHP application.

Note that you'll need to make sure your assemblies are declared as COM visible:

```
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
```

Here are two examples.

```
<?php
 $stack = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Collections.Stack");
 $stack->Push(".Net");
 $stack->Push("Hello ");
 echo $stack->Pop() . $stack->Pop();
?>
```

Another example demonstrating functionality of DOTNET class:

```
<?php

$full_assembly_string = 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a8425bc35256e463';
$full_class_name = 'System.Windows.Forms.Form';
$form = new DOTNET($full_assembly_string, $full_class_name);

// code to add buttons, menus, text, etc

$form->Show();

$form_event = '';
while($form_event !== 'close') {

  // handle form functions and events

  }
?>
```

Comment: It works well with .NET libraries. I couldn't ever load one of my own classes. Looks like ComVisible is not the only switch you have to pull to make that work.

Answer (score 2):

you are using the PHP Version 5.4.7 you should already have com_dotnet.dll 
if you dont have it you can download it on "[download](http://originaldll.com/file/php_com_dotnet.dll/29386.html)" and add to your ext/ path inside php directory.

Edit you php.ini file

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

**What you really need is this:**

- Enable COM-Visibility (I was wrong before)
- Sign your assembly (give it a "stong name", use "sn.exe" to create public-private-keys)
- Add your assembly to GAC (use "gacutil.exe")
- When you change your assembly, before adding it to GAC again, make sure your **AssemblyVersion** (not FileVersion) changes/goes up (you can go down as well)

*(you find those tools most probably in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\ ...", just google for their correct use, easy enough)*

---

That should do it.
In PHP (example):

```
<?php
    // use this kind of name, not path to dll or whatever
    // print your assemblly's full name in .NET and use that
    $name = "YourAssembly, Version=1.1.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fe6263478ac";
    $obj = new DOTNET($name, "YourNamespace.YourClass");
    echo "success\n";
?>
```

Oh yeah, vaibhav is right about "php.ini". I didn't have to edit it. It had the correct values (defaults maybe?).